# Can I move uipath application from desktop to cloud?

Tags: uipath-studio

I'm new to uipath. I developed a local application, It works fine locally.
My question is can I move this application to cloud, I mean the application needs mouse, keyboard, none of that is there.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

### UiPath and the Cloud

Can you move the UiPath application to the cloud? Not really.

I mean, you have [UiPath Orchestrator](https://www.theserverside.com/blog/Coffee-Talk-Java-News-Stories-and-Opinions/Create-your-first-RPA-robot-to-UiPath-Orchestrator-tutorial) where you can publish your robot and it hosts your UiPath packages, but the robot itself must be deployed to a Windows desktop, as it uses various Windows and .NET libraries to function.

### Server-side UiPath Development

So no, if you think your application can run entirely in the cloud, on a server-side hosting environment, then [UiPath automation](https://www.rpacertified.com/2020/09/09/rpa-uipath-automation-type.html) probably isn't the best way to implement your solution. It might be cheaper and easier to simply use the .NET framework, or even use [Java and Tomcat](https://www.theserverside.com/feature/Is-Apache-Tomcat-the-right-Java-application-server-for-you) if you really want to do server-side development right.

But essentially the answer is no. The robot has to have a desktop on which to run. UiPath robots aren't designed to run entirely in a cloud hosted environment.